# Не переводятся поля формы

Tags: python, django, i18n, django-cms

Добрый день! Пытаюсь сделать сайт на двух языках, на русском и английском.

Русский по умолчанию. Настроил локализацию, в итоге вместо адреса `/registration/` стало использоваться `/ru/registration/` и `/en/registration/`

Заголовок помещенный в h1 переводится - значит перевод работает, однако название полей формы, помещенные в  так и остались на русском в обоих языковых url. Использую последнюю Django 1.9, Python 3.

Ниже привел вырезки из основных файлов, помогите плииз разобраться.

**settings.py**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)
```

**корневой urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', views.home_page),
    url(r'', include('account.urls')),
)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
class UserRegistration(forms.Form):
    ...
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Фамилия'))
```

**templates/account/registration.html**

```
{% load i18n %}
<h1>{% trans "Регистрация нового пользователя" %}</h1>
<form action="." method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
</form>
```

**locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po**

```
#: account/forms.py:21
msgid "Фамилия"
msgstr "Last name"

#: templates/account/registration.html:22
msgid "Регистрация нового пользователя"
msgstr "Register new user"
```

Comment: Ты запускал compilemessages?

Comment: Оффтоп: обычно вроде переводы делают с английского на русский, а не наоборот

Comment: В качестве `_` какая функция используется?

Comment: Добавил вызов функции в файле forms.py. Часто бывает так, что сначала сайт делается на русском, а потом, к примеру у начальства может возникнуть желание добавить поддержку английского, поэтому я сразу решил пойти этим путем.

Comment: @DmitryKalinin - да конечно запускал, сначала mekemessages -l en.. затем compilemessages соответственно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `ugettext` переводит фразу в момент её вызова. А вызывается она у вас в момент создания класса с формой. А класс с формой создаётся во время импорта `forms.py` при инициализации Джанги и ещё ДО принятия каких-либо запросов от пользователя. Как следствие — текущий язык остаётся не определён, и функции ничего не остаётся, кроме как ничего не переводить.

Для того, чтобы не выполнять перевод сразу, а отложить его до момента вывода переводимой фразы, есть функция `ugettext_lazy` — она возвращает не переведённую строку, а специальный прокси-объект, у которого забирается перевод только в момент использования (в данном случае — в шаблоне, рисуемом при обработке запроса).

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
class UserRegistration(forms.Form):
    ...
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Фамилия'))
```

---

P.S. На случай, если доведётся использовать прокси-объект где-то вручную, получить перевод от него можно приведением к юникодной строке:

```
>>> t = _('Log in')
>>> print(t)
<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f2ae5b97b50>
>>> print(str(t))  # unicode(t) для Python 2
Войти
```

[Подробнее в документации](http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/i18n/translation.html#lazy-translation)

Comment: О да - заработало! Благодарю за помощь.. пойду дальше погружаться в изучение!!!

Comment: @wedoca стоит отмечать ответы, которые вам помогли, как принятые, чтобы те, кто будут искать ответ на тот же вопрос, смогли его легче найти.

Comment: Прошу прощения, я недавно стал пользоваться этим сервисом, как мне принять вопрос?

Comment: @wedoca слева под стрелочками галочка

Comment: Увидел.. спасибо.. а я постоянно пытался на стрелочку нажать, которая вверх...

Answer (score 0):

Для полей формы надо использовать `ugettext_lazy` вместо `ugettext`.